# Trying to use “Pit Remove” tool gives out “'ascii' codec can't encode character" error

Tags: qgis, python, unicode

It does not only happen with pit remove, but with other tools as well. I get this error in all of them.

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 158: ordinal not in range(128) See log for more details
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: character 0158 is a capital R with a caron. Could that be in the attribute table somewhere?

Comment: What is the full filepath of your input and output datasets?

Comment: What's in the log when you *checked it for more details*? Are you on an other-than-English filesystem? Is your input raster an Esri ASCII grid (AAIGRID) raster? if so can you have a look in the header for corruption? (the first few lines should be plain English as the tags are well defined *in English*)